# use scoped service inside httpclient

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I use a custom Singleton httpClient service, and a scoped UserInfo service which contains the data of the user who sent the request.

In startup.cs

```
services.AddScpoped<IUserInfo, UserInfo>();
services.AddHttpClient<MicroServiceClient>();
```

I want to add a custom header with data from the userInfo service in each request that is sent via the MicroServiceClient service. But I face a problem because i cannot use a scoped service inside a singelton.

Comment: Use HttpClient to only send messages, but messages can be created outside of `MicroServiceClient` within scoped service and passed to the singleton client.

Comment: Are you using ASP .NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject `IServiceProvider` into your typed http-client and start a scope on your own.

```cs
using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var userInfo = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUserInfo>();
    // more logic here
}
```

Keep in mind that manually starting a scope, in this case, is considered to be an anti-pattern called `ServiceLocatorPattern`. You can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern).